# django rest framework removing many to many fields in validated_data when doing partial_update

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My serializer includes two nested serializer , hence according the doc I am overriding this serializer's update method. However the validated_data field that is sent to this update method is "cleaned" and the many to many fields are not present.

serializer.initial_data is

**QueryDict: {u'exchange': [u'1', u'9']}**

The validated_data inside the update() of this ModelSerializer is

{'adgroup_name': u'adgroup_name', u'creative': [], validated_data inside the update( ) 'campaign_id': , **u'exchange': []**}

The field "exchange" is basically removed or cleaned ! How do I avoid this ?
Model:

```
class AdGroup(models.Model):
adgroup_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")
exchange = models.ManyToManyField(Exchange, verbose_name="Exchange")
creative = models.ManyToManyField(Creative, verbose_name="Creative")
```

Update code in the view:

```
    class AdGroupViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
        queryset = AdGroup.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        serializer_class = AdGroupSerializer
        filter_fields = ('campaign_id',)
        def update(self,

 request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
                instance = self.get_object()        
                serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)

                print 'view serializer data is'
                print serializer.initial_data
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                self.perform_update(serializer)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            except Exception as e:          
                print "update in viewset error "+str(e)
                traceback.print_exc()

        def perform_update(self, serializer):
                serializer.save()


        def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['partial'] = True
                print 'partial update called with'
                print request.data
            return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The serializer code is:

```
class AdGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exchange = ExchangeSerializer(many=True)
    creative = CreativeSerializer_reduced(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = AdGroup
        fields = ('id','name','exchange','creative')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            print 'serialzier update called and the validated_data is'
            print validated_data
            if validated_data['state']:
                print 'state is sent'
                instance.state = validated_data['state']

            if validated_data['exchange']:
                print 'exchange is  sent'
                print validated_data['exchange']
                instance.exchange = validated_data['exchange']

            if validated_data['creative']:
                print 'creaitve is sent'
                print validated_data['creative']
                instance.creative = validated_data['creative']

            instance.save()
            return instance
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info("Update Serializer error is "+str(e))
```

The Exchange serializer is:

```
class ExchangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Exchange
        fields = ('id','name', )
```

The Creaitve serializer is:

```
class CreativeSerializer_reduced(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Creative
        fields = ('id','creative_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing strikes me is that you declare a nested serializer and send flat IDs.
Serializer detects that you're sending exchange but none of the field is available therefore you have an empty list.

Comment: Yes . Looks like that was the issue. I had the front end sending list of ID's because it was easier to save to the DB when creating the object that had this M2M relationships. 
I am using two serializers now - one for getting ( which includes this nested way ) and the other for creating ( which is list of ID's).